# PHP SOAP send envelope to WSDL

Tags: php, curl, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I really hope that i managed to write correct title for this. Basically, i need to connect to make soap request to certain url, and retrieve data from there.

This is request that i need to send:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:rad="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Radixx.ConnectPoint.Request" xmlns:rad1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Radixx.ConnectPoint.Security.Request">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:RetrieveSecurityToken>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:RetrieveSecurityTokenRequest>
            <rad:CarrierCodes>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <rad:CarrierCode>
                  <rad:AccessibleCarrierCode>FZ</rad:AccessibleCarrierCode>
               </rad:CarrierCode>
            </rad:CarrierCodes>
            <rad1:LogonID>xxx</rad1:LogonID>
            <rad1:Password>xxxx</rad1:Password>
         </tem:RetrieveSecurityTokenRequest>
      </tem:RetrieveSecurityToken>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my code

```
$url = "http://uat.ops.connectpoint.flydubai.com/ConnectPoint.Security.svc?wsdl";
$data =  array(  "LogonID"=>"xxxxx",  "Password"=>"xxxxx");

$client = new SoapClient($url);

$client->__soapCall("RetrieveSecurityToken", $data);
```

And request error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'RetrieveSecurityToken'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 162. in J:\WORK\web\flyDubai\index.php:25 Stack trace: #0 J:\WORK\web\flyDubai\index.php(25): SoapClient->__soapCall('RetrieveSecurit...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in J:\WORK\web\flyDubai\index.php on line 25`
```

When i call __getTypes() i get (among other things):

```
struct RetrieveSecurityToken {
    string LogonID;
    string Password;
}
```

I guess this request that i make is not correct (maybe i should send whole xml converted to array), but i cant figure out how to send correct one?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling expects `RetrieveSecurityTokenRequest` parameter of type `RetrieveSecurityToken` that is defined in the included [XSD file](http://uat.ops.connectpoint.flydubai.com/ConnectPoint.Security.svc?xsd=xsd2). There you can see that it is extended from `CarrierInfo` adding `LogonID` and `Password` properties.

Base type `CarrierInfo` is defined in other [XSD file](http://uat.ops.connectpoint.flydubai.com/ConnectPoint.Security.svc?xsd=xsd3). It has a single property `CarrierCodes` of type `ArrayOfCarrierCode` which is an array of `CarrierCode` objects, each having a single `AccessibleCarrierCode` string property.

In the WSDL, `CarrierInfo` is specified as nillable (allowing `<rad:CarrierCodes xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />`) and can be empty array (allowing `<rad:CarrierCodes/>`) but the service is replying with errors in those cases.

So this is why you should probably create request following the sample XML you posted in the question, having at least one carrier code:

```php
$code = new StdClass;
$code->AccessibleCarrierCode = "FZ";

$data = new StdClass;
$data->CarrierCodes = array($code);

$data->LogonID = "xxxxx";
$data->Password = "xxxxx";

$client = new SoapClient($url);
$response = $client->RetrieveSecurityToken(array("RetrieveSecurityTokenRequest" => $data));

var_dump($response);
```